# Как отправить xml сообщение методом POST

Tags: php, xml, email, backend

Ниже приведен пример xml-сообщения которое должно быть отправлено методом POST на адрес https://anketa.alfabank.ru/alfaform-pos/endpoint

Допустим у меня есть форма на сайте

```
<form action="https://anketa.alfabank.ru/alfaform-pos/endpoint"  method="post">
         <button>Отправить</button> 
        </form>
```

как реализовать отправку?

```
<inParams>
    <brokerInfo>
        <Id>1</ Id>
            <logotype> http://www.logo.ru/logotype.png</logotype>
    </brokerInfo>

    <companyInfo>
        <inn>1111111111</inn>
        <referer>http://ulmart.ru/my_endpoint</referer>
    </companyInfo>

    <creditInfo>
        <reference>RFE003453PO</reference>
        <firstPayment>0</firstPayment>
        <creditPeriod>15</creditPeriod>
        <creditProductCode>ILEF</creditProductCode>
        <shopCode>AABB01_IS1</shopCode>

    </creditInfo>

    <clientInfo>
        <lastname>Арсентьев</lastname>
        <firstname>Антон</firstname>
        <middlename>Андреевич</middlename>
        <passportSeries>1212</passportSeries>
        <passportNumber>123456</passportNumber>
        <email>lol4e@gmail.com</email>
        <mobphone>9197262902</mobphone>
    </clientInfo>

    <specificationList>
        <specificationListRow>
            <category>CRT_TV</category> <code>#123</code>
            <description>Samsung</description>
            <amount>1</amount>
            <price>25000</price>
            <action>10/10/10</action>
        </specificationListRow>
        <specificationListRow>
            <category>MOBILE_PHONE</category> <code>#1222</code>
            <description>HTC</description>
            <amount>2</amount>
            <price>15000</price>
            <image>http://www.photo.ru/product.png</image>
            © 2001–2016 Альфа-Банк 8
        </specificationListRow>
    </specificationList>
</inParams>
```

Comment: Так а что у вас не получилось? Как пытаетесь решить данную задачу?

Comment: как реализовать отправку , каким образом

Comment: cURL http://www.php.net/curl

Comment: Я не понимаю , что это как это реализовать?

Comment: Хотя бы пример киньте

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yC81nrax вот пример 0_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас должна быть документация по данной `API` банка в ней есть все примеры как и чем лучше отправлять, если ее у вас нет запросите ее у банка или загуглите возможно она есть в открытом доступе. 
Обычно у для такого запроса нужна регистрация в банке и получение закрытого уникального токена доступа и обычно для таких вот запросов банки пишут `API` на `SOAP`.
 
Если получить документацию не удалось то попробовать можно `cURL PHP`
Пример кода для отправки `XML` через `POST`:
`$input_xml = '<inParams>
    <brokerInfo>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <logotype> http://www.logo.ru/logotype.png</logotype>
    </brokerInfo>
    <companyInfo>
        <inn>1111111111</inn>
        <referer>http://ulmart.ru/my_endpoint</referer>
    </companyInfo>
    <creditInfo>
        <reference>RFE003453PO</reference>
        <firstPayment>0</firstPayment>
        <creditPeriod>15</creditPeriod>
        <creditProductCode>ILEF</creditProductCode>
        <shopCode>AABB01_IS1</shopCode>
    </creditInfo>
    <clientInfo>
        <lastname>Арсентьев</lastname>
        <firstname>Антон</firstname>
        <middlename>Андреевич</middlename>
        <passportSeries>1212</passportSeries>
        <passportNumber>123456</passportNumber>
        <email>lol4e@gmail.com</email>
        <mobphone>9197262902</mobphone>
    </clientInfo>
    <specificationList>
        <specificationListRow>
            <category>CRT_TV</category> <code>#123</code>
            <description>Samsung</description>
            <amount>1</amount>
            <price>25000</price>
            <action>10/10/10</action>
        </specificationListRow>
        <specificationListRow>
            <category>MOBILE_PHONE</category> <code>#1222</code>
            <description>HTC</description>
            <amount>2</amount>
            <price>15000</price>
            <image>http://www.photo.ru/product.png</image>
            © 2001–2016 Альфа-Банк 8
        </specificationListRow>
    </specificationList>
</inParams>';
$url = "https://anketa.alfabank.ru/alfaform-pos/endpoint";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);`